# Siebel Version Upgrade

Tags: oracle, version, upgrade, crm, siebel

I currently use Siebel version 8.1.1.11, I would like to upgrade version 21.2 or 21.4 version. Have you ever been partake of something this experience. If so that, is there any tools to this upgrade? Can you share your experience?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, this operation is complicated if there are many customizations are made in the version 8.1.1.11 in order to meet the requirements of version 21.2 or 21.4 and mostly needs long-term project to implement the upgrade and minimize the number of possible issues. However, if the current version has little customizations. Then, there might be a chance to upgrade, but still the gap is big between the two versions.